# Connection closed by EC2 IP - port 22

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Below is the security group(first one) applied to EC2 instance.

### [image]

Rules for this security group is:

### [image]

But ssh command give below error:

```
$ ssh -i ./xyz.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xx port 22
```

---

Why ssh client is unable to connect to ubuntu instance type?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141942/best-stack-exchange-site-for-asking-about-amazon-aws

Comment: Add -v or -vv to the ssh arguments to get details of where it is failing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [default user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html) is different based on OS.  Use ubuntu instead of ec2-user.